# button click event from java script not working in IE 9

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, internet-explorer-9

this is my javascript code :

```
document.getElementById("<%= btnUpload.ClientID %>").click();
```

This code is working perfectly in all other browsers except IE 9. what could be the possibility ?

Comment: You may be trying to get a reference to an element before it exists, you need to ensure your code is not run until the DOM is fully loaded see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded

Comment: as i mentioned it working perfectly in all other browsers. just exception in IE 9

Comment: You need to show some more of your code. Where is the javascript located in the page  in relation to the content?

Comment: Try setting ClientIDMode="Static" so that the id remains the same when the page is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use .on()

document.getElementById("<%= btnUpload.ClientID %>").on('click',function () {});
});
this is JQuery, but I'm assuming you are using it. If not you can use OnClick function from Javascript.